# Keep GROUP_CONCAT from grouping NULL values?

Tags: mysql, group-by

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GROUP BY - do not group NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588935/group-by-do-not-group-null)

When doing a `GROUP_CONCAT()` and using `GROUP BY` on a column, if the column value for any of the results is `NULL`, it groups all those into one record. Is it possible to keep records separate if the `GROUP BY` column is `NULL`?