# Function in web2py groupby clause

Tags: sql, grouping, web2py

I want to have all the NULL rows in a groupby clause in separate groups. In SQL this would be something like

`` GROUP BY IFNULL(`Y`, `X`); ``

(see [GROUP BY - do not group NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588935/group-by-do-not-group-null)).

How do I do this in web2py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many cases, you can pass SQL strings to the DAL methods, so in this case, something like:

```
grouped_ids = 'GROUP_CONCAT(`id`)'
rows = db(query).select(db.mytable.myfield, grouped_ids,
                        groupby='IFNULL(`myfield`, `id`)')
print rows[0][grouped_ids]
```

The above will use the `id` value (which is unique) rather than `myfield` when `myfield` is null.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I guess I might be stuck if trying to use the DAL to do GROUP_CONCAT() as in that SO example, though?

Comment: No, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` as well -- see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again. Is there by any chance a way to rename the 'grouped_ids' column in the returned rows, so that it's not called 'GROUP_CONCAT(`id`)'?

Comment: There are ways, but there is some complexity involved. Depending on what you intend to do with the output, there may be simpler alternatives (e.g., store the raw SQL in a variable and use that to access the field, as above). It's probably best if you open a new question and explain exactly what you need to do with the results.