# GROUP BY not NULL values

Tags: mysql, group-by, hive

I have a **Hive** table (no primary key) that looks similar to:

```
X      Y
-------------
1      a
2      a
2      a
1      b
1      b
2      c
2      NULL
1      NULL
2      d
```

Note the `X` column can be values other than just 1 and 2.

The query if I don't want to do `GROUP BY` would be:

```
SELECT X, Y
FROM my_table
```

I want to do a `GROUP BY` operation on column `Y` where the value isn't `NULL`. Moreover, I want to keep the `NULL` value for `Y`. So the resulting table would look like:

```
X      Y
-------------
1      a
1      b
2      c
2      NULL
1      NULL
2      d
```

Note, I don't care which X gets selected.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588935/group-by-do-not-group-null), my query would be:

```
SELECT 
    IFNULL(Y, UUID()) AS unq_Y,
    any(X) AS X
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY unq_Y
```

However, `unq_Y` would be whatever `UUID()` returns if `Y` is `NULL`, the query result would be:

```
X      unq_Y
-------------
1      a
1      b
2      c
2      UUID()_result
1      UUID()_result
2      d
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: I added the `mysql` tag because the same problem applies (although the solution might be different).

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY, which may prove problematic in due course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, I can just put the `NULL` check in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT 
    any(Y) AS Y,
    any(X) AS X
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY COALESCE(Y, CAST(reflect("java.util.UUID", "randomUUID") AS STRING));
```

My version of Hive doesn't support `IFNULL()` so `COALESCE()` is a good alternative. My version Hive also doesn't support `UUID()` so I called `reflect()` to get unique id.

Comment: Do you want to display all the rows having `y` as `null`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The value for `y` would be `null`, but `x` wouldn't be `null` right?

Comment: yeah...that's what I am asking. Do you want to display all values of `x` when `y` is `null` ? or any one value of `x` will be fine?

Comment: I want to display all values of `x` when `y` is null, hence why I asked I only wanted to do a `GROUP BY` when `y` is not `NULL`. I tested the results for both our answers on SQL Fiddle, the outputs are the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple if the order of result set is not important. Just use `union all` as follows:

```
SELECT     
    X AS X,
    Y AS unq_Y
FROM my_table 
where y is not null
GROUP BY unq_Y
    union all
SELECT     
    X AS X,
    Y AS unq_Y
FROM my_table 
where y is null
;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c61f6/7/0)

Hope it helps!

Comment: This was my original fallback plan. I wanted to avoid querying the same table twice over something so simple.