# Laravel select groupby only not nullable values

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a model Products. In the table there are columns id,description,barcode,sizebarcode,price. Sizebarcode column has some values and also nullable values. I want to grouping sizebarcode column where are not nullable values. Null values are directly selected without grouping. I want to omit nullable values when grouping.

I want to select all unique values in sizebarcode and also with all nullable values

Controller.php

```
$products = Category::where('slug',$slug)->first()->products_front()->paginate(12);

return view('page.shop',compact('products'))
```

Model.php

```
 public function products_front(){
return $this->hasMany('App\Product','cat_id','id')
    ->groupBy('sizebarcode')
    ->orderBy('created_at','asc');
```

}

[My table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1ce7.png)

[What are I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dpPA.png)

Comment: What result done this code ?

Comment: @Goms I want to select unique values from table. But all my problem is when i grouping, nullable values are not selected

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588935/group-by-do-not-group-null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
public function products_front(){
return $this->hasMany('App\Product','cat_id','id')
->groupBy(DB::raw('ifnull(sizebarcode,id)')
->orderBy('created_at','asc');
```

Comment: @asfal c Amazing answer... Thank you very much.  It solves my problem