# how can I only group non-null values and null not group

Tags: laravel

As the title I need to group 2 values and the 2nd value if it's null then no group is not null then group

```
$orderBrand = $this->orderProductModel->select('*');

$orderBrand = $orderBrand->join('dtb_product', 'dtb_order_product.product_id', '=', 'dtb_product.product_id')
                ->join('dtb_order', 'dtb_order_product.order_id', 'dtb_order.order_id')
                ->groupBy('dtb_product.product_brand_id', 'dtb_order.user_id');
```

if `dtb_order.user_id === null` not group and not null group

Comment: the null dtb_order.user_id result ... where should be grouped? or you don't want them to be in the result?

Comment: Still in the results.

Comment: well, if they in the results, then should be grouped somewhere, is not?

Comment: No need to group, it just at the same result as at first group only but user_id is not null

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588935/group-by-do-not-group-null

Comment: I've seen it but don't understand.